# Progress 4GL: Cannot READ-JSON the JSON that was written

Tags: json, openedge, progress-4gl

I am having a problem with Progress READ-JSON where it is not accepting the JSON that was output by WRITE-JSON. We are using TRACKING-CHANGES with a dataset with a nested data-relation.

```
OUTPUT TO "debug.txt".

DEFINE VARIABLE lcString AS LONGCHAR NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hdsBox AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lOk AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttEmployee NO-UNDO
    BEFORE-TABLE ttEmployeeBefore
    FIELD eid AS INTEGER
    FIELD empname AS CHAR.
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttBox NO-UNDO
    BEFORE-TABLE ttBoxBefore
    FIELD eid AS INTEGER SERIALIZE-HIDDEN
    FIELD boxid AS INTEGER
    FIELD boxdesc AS CHAR.
DEFINE DATASET dsBox FOR ttEmployee, ttBox
    DATA-RELATION relat1 FOR ttEmployee, ttBox RELATION-FIELDS (ttEmployee.eid, ttBox.eid) NESTED.

CREATE ttEmployee.
CREATE ttBox.
ASSIGN ttEmployee.eid = 1
    ttEmployee.empname = "Ian"
    ttBox.eid = 1
    ttBox.boxid = 10
    ttBox.boxdesc = "Ians box".
    hdsBox = DATASET dsBox:HANDLE.

ASSIGN TEMP-TABLE ttEmployee:TRACKING-CHANGES = YES
    TEMP-TABLE ttBox:TRACKING-CHANGES = YES.

CREATE ttBox.
ASSIGN ttBox.eid = 1
    ttBox.boxid = 11
    ttBox.boxdesc = "Stewarts box"
    /*ttEmployee.empname = "Stewart"*/ .

ASSIGN lOk = hdsBox:WRITE-JSON("LONGCHAR", lcString,FALSE , "UTF-8", FALSE, FALSE, TRUE).

ASSIGN TEMP-TABLE ttEmployee:TRACKING-CHANGES = NO
    TEMP-TABLE ttBox:TRACKING-CHANGES = NO.

MESSAGE lOk ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(1) SKIP.
MESSAGE STRING(lcString) SKIP.

ASSIGN lOk = hdsBox:READ-JSON("LONGCHAR":U, lcString, "EMPTY":U) NO-ERROR.

MESSAGE lOk ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(1) SKIP.
```

This example generates the following output:

```
yes
{"dsBox":{"prods:hasChanges":true,"ttEmployee":[{"eid":1,"empname":"Ian","ttBox":[{"boxid":10,"boxdesc":"Ians box"},{"prods:id":"ttBox96513","prods:rowState":"created","boxid":11,"boxdesc":"Stewarts box"}]}],"prods:before":{}}}
no Error parsing JSON: expected string, but found bracket. (15358)
```

If I take out the comment on line 35, then it works, which leads me to believe it is a Progress bug.

I am using OpenEdge 11.4.

Comment: What version of Progress are you using? I tried it on 11.6.3 and it worked with or without the comment.

Comment: I am using 11.4. Maybe they fixed it in 11.6. Is the JSON output the same in 11.6?

Comment: Yes, they're identical except for the ID "ttBox96513". No extra/missing brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Progress bug. To fix, I need to insert a meaningless field into the before-table of the JSON.

```
"prods:before":{"Progress11.4bug":"Need this string or Progress will barf"}
```

Progress doesn't like the before-table to be empty for some reason.